# Is there a way to add metadata to a docbook article at the the end of the article

Tags: docbook

I'm rendering a docbook article from the top down and if I encounter certain errors I need to put in a flag into the metadata. What's the best tag I can add at the end to represent this flag? I am writing articleinfo as the first tag in the article so I can't use that. Is there a best practice for this?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you have a some little misunderstandings about DocBook.

**Note:** I assume you use DocBook 4.5 because of `articleinfo` mentioned. This element is deprecated in DocBook 5.x in favor of `info` element that is common metadata root element for all top level structure types (`books`, `articles`, etc.).

Here are some points you need to put your attention on.

#### Type or errors

1. There are several types of errors you can faced (assume you have well-formed xml files - this can be an another fundamental type of error):

   - **Structure** errors - i.e. validating again DocBook schema.
   - **Layout** errors - i.e. you don't like the way your article is presented on a print matter.
   - **Logical-based** errors concerning the text matter - i.e. you don't want to have long sentences, etc.

Depending on the error type there are different ways for fixing:

- **Structure** errors - you can't put a sign of this type of error WITHIN a destination DocBook file, because the structure error prevents destination DocBook to be processed and/or generated.
- **Layout** errors - this is fully depend on you final destination (print, html or just xml) so the answer is - *it depends*
- **Logical-based** errors - here you are fully qualified to do what you want and to put any information you want within your DocBook file (see **Usecase 1** below).

#### DocBook as a document vocabulary

DocBook is a XML-based vocabulary so you can make any XML -> XML processing using xslt stylesheets other than DocBook XSLT Stylesheets (and its customizations).

**Usecase 1**: you want to check if your article contains some element (i.e. `guimenu`). If yes, you want to put a sign within your articleinfo element. You write your own xsl stylesheet to produce final DocBook file with a sign within depend on your conditions.This stylesheet DOESN'T have to be any connection with a a default DocBook XSL Stylesheets.

Comment: Yeah I'm checking for an error within the text that's being put into a docbook. However the program is looking at the text and converting it into docbook in a top down way as it parses the text. I want to prefer keeping articleinfo/info as the first tag so if the parser hits a text error it can add a flag to the end of the document and then xsl picks up that flag and adds a watermark to the first page (or the headers).

Comment: I suggest you need to provide a MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to look at.